# Remove Google Ads from Google Maps search

Tags: google-maps

I've Google bar in Google maps in my project, whenever I search something it displays Google ads along. How to remove these Google ads?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that doing so would breach your TOS with Google.

Comment: that's what I supsect, too, since google provides the services for free but use advertising for its revenue.